# Using co-planarity to determine the points inside a triangle

Tags: linear-algebra, triangles, projective-geometry, affine-geometry

**Context:** I am studying a graphics textbook which is analyzing something called a "3D projective transformation", which is neither linear nor affine but somehow preserves co-linearity and co-planarity:

> Co-linearity means that, if three or more points are on a single line, the transformed points will also be on some single line. [Co-planarity has an analogous meaning.]

The textbook makes the claim:

> As a result of [the preservation of co-planarity], we know that for points on a fixed triangle, we will have $z_n = ax_n + by_n + c$ for some fixed $a$, $b$, and $c$. Thus, the correct $z_n$ value for a point can be computed using linear interpoluation over the $2D$ image domain as long as we know its value at the three vertices of a triangle.

Here I am assuming that the book is saying that if $f$ is a 3D projective transformation, and if $a$, $b$, and $c$ are points in the domain of $f$. Then we can determine some point inside the triangle determined by these 3 points by the equation

$$
f(p) = (x_n, y_n, z_n)
$$

such that $z_n = a x_n + b y_n + c$.

Am I getting this right?  The textbook makes this point without any rigor. Is this some well known fact about triangles that somebody can point me to or explain?

Comment: The equation of a plane (that is not perpendicular to the xy plane) is always of the form $z=ax+by+c$ ...

Comment: If $a$, $b$, and $c$ are all vectors, and if $x$ and $y$ are real numbers, then the expression $ax + by + c$ returns a vector.  Yet $z$ is supposed to be a real number.  So how does the equation $z = ax + by + c$, as you write it, make sense?

Comment: I could not infer from the block-quote above that $a,b,c$ are supposed to be vectors (because that would make $z_n$ a vector and it is strange to write $ax_n$, i.e., "vector times scalar" instead of "scalar times vector")

Comment: Then what are $a$, $b$, and $c$ from your interpretation?